# Can't instantiate factories after updating to Springboot 3 and SpringFramework 6

Tags: java, spring, maven, boot

Everything compiles, but I'm getting an error with the spring framework cloud configuration. The errors are all within the compiled dependencies, so I'm not sure what I am missing here. Any ideas?

I'm getting this error in particular.

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLocationResolver] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolver]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FailureHandler.lambda$throwing$0(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:650)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FailureHandler.lambda$handleMessage$3(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:674)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:231)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.<init>(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.createConfigDataLocationResolvers(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.<init>(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigDataEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:150)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:197)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at navy.chino.fields.FieldsApp.main(FieldsApp.java:68)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Log types cannot be injected, please use DeferredLogFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$new$0(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver.lambda$ofSupplied$3(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:585)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver$1.resolve(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:601)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver.lambda$and$0(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:551)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$ArgumentResolver$1.resolve(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:601)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.resolveArgs(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:387)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:377)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228)
    ... 46 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Trying to upgrade an application to use Spring Framework 6 and all of the other updates needed along the way.

Comment: hi& welcome! Spring cloud is not (dependency) managed by spring boot! (for spring-boot:3, we should use "2022.0.x aka Kilburn"... there + logging/bootstrap config, where I'd investigate next) ([migration-3 guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide), [spring-cloud-overview](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview) )